# If I put my custom directive inside ng-if, its link function is never called

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive, angular-ng-if

Even though the element is shown eventually.

If I put it inside `ng-show` instead of `ng-if`, it works, but it needs to work inside `ng-if` as well.

Both `ng-if` and `ng-show` are accompanied by `ng-cloak`.

Custom directive:

```
var customDirective = [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '?^^customSuperAttribute',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      console.log('link called')
      //...
    }
  }
]
angular.module(module.exports).directive('customAttribute', customDirective)
```

Use of directive:

```
<span ng-cloak ng-if="variable" custom-attribute>abc</span>
```

The task of the `link` function is to replace the `span`'s text.

Comment: Not clear how your code is related to question description.

Comment: I added example HTML.

Comment: Everything works fine, the directive gets called and does what it should do, **except** if used in conjunction with `ng-if`.

Comment: Works fine for me. If you can provide a demo it would help.

Comment: After creating a fiddle I see you are right: http://jsfiddle.net/31s3LLbx/3

Comment: I should have done this before, the `console.log` message appeared in my app as well, but I overlooked it. I realized my problem is more complex.